# Múltiples valores en un printf

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente código que busca un valor diferente de cero en un array:

```
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
            if(matriz[i][j] != 0){
                printf("En el renglón %d hay un valor en la columna %d\n", i+1, j+1);
            }
        }
    }
```

La salida que obtengo en la siguiente:

```
En el renglón 1 hay un valor en la columna 14
En el renglón 2 hay un valor en la columna 13
En el renglón 4 hay un valor en la columna 15
En el renglón 5 hay un valor en la columna 4
En el renglón 5 hay un valor en la columna 6
```

Me pregunta es ¿Existe alguna manera para que en el caso del 5 sólo obtenga `En el renglón 5 hay un valor en la columna 4, 6`. Gracias.

Comment: Los valores que imprimes no corresponden al código, agrega el código correcto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que lo que quieres es "agrupar" todos los índices de columna correspondientes a una misma fila, en caso de que tengas varios resultados para esa fila.

No es una cuestión de si `printf()` puede hacerlo, si no de modificar tu código para que detecte si es el primer valor que ha encontrado en esa fila (en cuyo caso imprime un mensaje como el que tú ponías, pero sin en retorno de carro final, por si hay que añadir más columnas después), o si ya había sido encontrado un valor en esa fila (en cuyo caso imprime sólo el nuevo índice de columna, separado por coma, de nuevo sin retorno de carro por si hay más). Y una vez terminada la iteración para esa fila, se imprimiría el retorno de carro final (sólo si se encontró algún valor en esa fila) antes de pasar a la siguiente.

El código sería:

```
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    found = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
        if(matriz[i][j] != 0){
            if (!found)
                printf("En el renglón %d hay un valor en la columna %d", i+1, j+1);
            else
                printf(", %d", j+1);
            found = 1;
        }
    }
    if (found) printf("\n");
}
```

Por dar un ejemplo completo compilable y verificable (cosa que deberías haber hecho tú):

```
#include <stdio.h>   // para printf
#include <string.h>  // Para memset

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    int rows = 5, N = 15;
    int matriz[rows][N];
    int found=0;

    // Rellenar con ceros la matriz
    memset(matriz, 0, rows*N*sizeof(int));
    // Poner algunos valores distintos de cero
    matriz[0][13] = matriz[1][12] = matriz[3][14] = matriz[4][3] = matriz[4][5] = 1;

    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        found = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
            if(matriz[i][j] != 0){
                if (!found)
                    printf("En el renglón %d hay un valor en la columna %d", i+1, j+1);
                else
                    printf(", %d", j+1);
                found = 1;
            }
        }
        if (found) printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Si lo ejecutas, sale lo que pedías:

```
En el renglón 1 hay un valor en la columna 14
En el renglón 2 hay un valor en la columna 13
En el renglón 4 hay un valor en la columna 15
En el renglón 5 hay un valor en la columna 4, 6
```

Dejo como "Ejercicio para el lector" :-) que en casos como el último ponga "en las columnas" en vez de "en la columna".

Comment: Muchas gracias. Si funciono la solución.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo de cuando dices que imprimir:

```
En el renglón 5 hay un valor en la columna 4, 6
```

... es que ese 6, sería el valor correspondiente a la fila 5 y la columna 4, si es así: el printf sería:

```
printf("En el renglón %d hay un valor en la columna %d, %d\n", i+1, j+1, matriz[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intente otra manera aunque la de @abulafia se me hace un poco más viable y de hecho él incluyo para que pusiera una coma. De igual manera publico aquí el código que también puede resolver la problemática:

```
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        printf("En el renglón %d hay valores en las columnas: ", i+1);
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
            if(matriz[i][j] != 0){
                printf("%d ", j+1);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

En este caso imprimirá sólo por renglón la frase `En el renglón %d hay valores en las columnas:` e imprimirá las columnas que contienen valores diferentes a 0.

```
En el renglón 6 hay valores en las columnas: 11 
En el renglón 7 hay valores en las columnas: 6 12 
En el renglón 8 hay valores en las columnas: 1 2 
En el renglón 9 hay valores en las columnas: 2 14
```